# Graphics file not found

Tags: graphics, floats

I'm attempting to include image files in my LaTeX document whose code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where 'fig1.jpg' is in the same folder as this LaTeX file but still on compiling I'm getting the error 'fig1 not found'.Is there any way this error be rectified and what might be the reason behind this error?

Comment: Are you compiling with latex or pdflatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm compiling with LaTeX using 'latex f1.tex'.Anyway should that make any difference?

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference, latex can't handle jpg but pdflatex can.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks it worked like a charm.Just out of curiosity, any idea why it wasn't working while compiling with latex in the first place?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is a duplicate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/239201/10898

Comment: Glad to hear its working. Since your two questions are related, I recommend you to edit one so that it reflects your problem. As it is, the two questions are considered duplicates of each other and one of them will be closed. Since an answer is already provided by @UlrikeFischer, I recommend him to post the respective solution. Welcome to TeX.SX.

Comment: @azetina: I'm a woman. And I'm quite confident that some duplicate of this question exists already and that one could delete this one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh am sorry. My apologies madam. Je suis désolé :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,  Ulrike Fischer has given a brief answer (I up-voted her comment, accordingly), I will just detail it a bit.
The only format you can include while compiling with latex is Encapsulated PostScript (EPS). Because an EPS file declares the size of the image, it makes it easy for systems like LaTeX to arrange the text and the graphics in the best way.

If you are compiling with pdflatex to produce a PDF, you have a wider choice. You can insert:

- JPG
- PNG
- PDF
- EPS

Choosing one of these formats will heavily depend on the graphic itself. I you are including a photo, for example, then **JPG** will be your best choice. If you are including a non-vector diagram, a screenshot ...etc, then you may choose a **PNG** format. **PDF** on the other hand, can handle bit-map images as well as vector graphics. Therefore, it is the preferred choice for vector graphics. But for bit-map images, **JPG** and **PNG** are better because they occupy less disk space. **EPS** is also a high-quality vector graphics format, but it needs some configuration. The `epstopdf` package should be installed in your system (It actually is in current systems). If this is still not sufficient, then you need to load this package after `graphicx`, besides, you also need to give your compiler the permission to convert **EPS**  file to **PDF**. This is done by adding the option, for example `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex`, to your compiler command.

Comment: In current texsystems epstopdf doesn't need --shell-escape as it is in the list of  applications which are allowed to run without it.

Comment: You are right, just in case of an older system. Many thanks.